# Selenium webdriver button locator

Tags: selenium, webdriver

which locator i have to choose, to identify this button

```
<button
    class="proceedButton btn-4 btn-4c icon-arrow-right btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block width320 proceedButtonAnimate"
    ng-click="validateAndProceedWeb(rechargeForm)"
    data-horizontal=""
    data-style="fill"
    ng-disabled="checkoutDisable ? 'disabled' : ''"
    tabindex="0" aria-disabled="">
        Proceed to Recharge
        <span class="progress">
            <span
                class="progress-inner"
                ng-style="{width : ( widthProgress + '%' ) }"
                style="">
            </span>
        </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer accurately unless we can see the entire DOM.  There may be other identical buttons in the DOM for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

The `proceedButton` class name, as opposed to other class names, is *data-oriented* and not layout-oriented. Looks readable and reliable:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.proceedButton"));
```

You might as well use button's text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(., 'Proceed to Recharge')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

With Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'proceedButton')]"));
```

Comment: In that case, please mark the answer as being useful (by clicking on the upper arrow).